# User registration form: Give username "username n+1" value, if and when n is already used

Tags: forms

I'm using the first & last name in the user registration form to generate the username for the new user:

```
$firstname = $form_state['values']['field_firstname'][LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'];
$lastname = $form_state['values']['field_lastname'][LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'];
$username = $firstname.''.$lastname;
$result = db_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM {users} WHERE name = :name", array(':name' => $username));
$results_number = $result->rowCount();
if ($results_number == 0) {
    $form_state['values']['name'] = $username;
}
else {
    $i = 1;
    $username = $firstname.''.$lastname.''.$i;
    while ($results_number > 0) {
        $result = db_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM {users} WHERE name = :name", array(':name' => $username));
        $results_number = $result->rowCount();
        $i++;
        $username = $firstname.''.$lastname.''.$i;
        $form_state['values']['name'] = $username;
    }
}
```

But I get an infinite loop. There is a problem with that while loop, any suggestions on the best way to fix that?

Comment: `rowCount()` wont work with `SELECT COUNT(*)`. And Drupal user name is unique. With out `LIKE` statement if you are fetching value with user name, always you will get Row Count value is 1.

Comment: the count part I understand, I must have missed it in some terrible way - the 2nd part should work though, $i is increased every time the number of results is > 0, no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So here is what I used to increment the username's suffix by 1 if the initial value is not found:

```
function increment_string($str, $separator, $first = 1) {
    preg_match('/(.+)'.$separator.'([0-9]+)$/', $str, $match);
    return isset($match[2]) ? $match[1].$separator.($match[2] + 1) : $str.$separator.$first;
}

$username = $firstname . ' ' . $lastname;
$result = db_query("SELECT uid FROM {users} WHERE name = :name", array(':name' => $username));
$results_number = $result->rowCount();
    if ($results_number == 0) {
        $form_state['values']['name'] = $username;  
    }
    else {
    while ($results_number >= 1) {
        $username = increment_string($username_to_store, ' ');
        $result = db_query('SELECT uid FROM {users} WHERE name LIKE :name_pattern', array(':name_pattern' => db_like($username)));
        $results_number = $result->rowCount();
    }
    $form_state['values']['name'] = $username;  
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below solution.

```
$firstname = $form_state['values']['field_firstname'][LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'];
$lastname = $form_state['values']['field_lastname'][LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'];
$username = $firstname.''.$lastname;
$result = db_query("SELECT uid FROM {users} WHERE name like '$username%'");
$results_number = $result->rowCount();
if($results_number == 0){
  $form_state['values']['name'] = $username;
}else{
  $form_state['values']['name'] = $username.$results_number;
}
```

Comment: This solution fails when at least one user gets deleted from the system. e.g. we have username_1 and username_2 and username_3 and username_2 is deleted. Then the above fails.

Comment: `db_like()` should be instead used.